# Como hacer uso del $filter AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como puedo capturar en `$scope.personConOferta` la persona que tiene `oferta`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="person in personas">
     {{ person }}     
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.personas = [
      {
         "Codigo": 1,
         "Name": "alberto",
         "Offerta": [
            {
              "precio": 10000,
              "lugar": "Medellin"
            },
            {
              "precio": 2000000,
              "lugar": "Bogota"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Codigo": 2,
         "Name": "albertoPalacios",
         "Offerta": []
      }
    ]
    $scope.personConOferta = $filter('filter')($scope.personas, { Offerta.length > 0 }, true);
    $scope.personSinOferta = $filter('filter')($scope.personas, { Offerta.length == 0 }, true);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activa el modo estricto para que solo te filtre por coincidencias exactas. Esto se hace agregando true después del criterio de búsqueda.

```
$scope.personAlberto = $filter('filter')($scope.personas, { Name: "alberto" }, true);
$scope.personAlbertoPalacios = $filter('filter')($scope.personas, { Name: "albertoPalacios" }, true);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: tengo otra duda puedes resolverla? quedo atento

Comment: en qué puedo ayudarte?

Comment: mira mi publicación editada

Comment: Tendrías que hacer un filtro personalizado como indican en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597088/7977890) de StackOverflow.
Yo te recomendaría usar el filtro isEmpty en [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).